# Data StackExchange Server down

Tags: bug, data-explorer

I am not sure where to post the news, but the Data Stack Exchange server is down. Please somebody take care of the issue.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/264734/up-voted-comments

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249761/sede-error-when-trying-to-run-query

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been asked on MSE. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249761/sede-error-when-trying-to-run-query

Comment: Another on MSE - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249675/cant-explore-stack-exchange-data-explorer-errors-trying-to-build-new-query-and